# angularjs perform action after $rootScope.$broadcast is complete

Tags: angularjs

I have created a single page admin application using angularjs. The application has header, footer, left tab panel and content area. Something similar to this link http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_2_angularjs/index.html#/dashboard.html

Starting point is main.js which has the header controller, footer controller and left tab controller. I load different pages inside the content area based on tab selection. This is configured using $stateProvider as shown below. There are about 6 tabs.

**Content of main.js**

```
MyApp.controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
$scope.runSimulation = function(){      
        $rootScope.$broadcast('SaveAll').then(function(){
           //Run process on server when save all is finished on all 6 tabs
        });
    }
}]);

MyApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab1");  
    $stateProvider
    // Tab1
    .state('tab1', {
        url: "/tab1",
        templateUrl: path + "/views/tab1.html",            
        data: {pageTitle: 'First Page'},
        controller: "Tab1Controller",
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'MyApp',
                    insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', 
                    files: [
                            path + 'js/controllers/Tab1Controller.js',
                    ] 
                });
            }]
        }
    })

    // Tab2
    .state('tab2', {
        url: "/tab2",
        templateUrl: path + "/views/tab2.html",            
        data: {pageTitle: 'Second Page'},
        controller: "Tab2Controller",
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'MyApp',
                    insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', 
                    files: [
                            path + 'js/controllers/Tab1Controller.js',
                    ] 
                });
            }]
        }
    })    

}]);
```

Each tab controller js file contains one service for getting and manipulating data. i.e. Tab1Model, Tab2Model etc. The structure of the each tabcontroller file is something as shown below.

**content of individual tab file**

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('Tab1Controller',['$scope', '$rootScope', 
function($scope, $rootScope, {
    //Get data using tab1Model and update UI

 //----------- Save data ------------------------------------------
    $rootScope.$on('SaveAll', function () {
        tab1Model.putData(arr);
    });
]);

//Data model
angular.module('MyApp').factory('tab1Model', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$Http',  function($rootScope, $q, $http){

//get data from database using $http get
// .......some get code goes here.....

//Save data to database using $http put 
 model.putData = function(data){
     var deferred =  $q.defer();
        $http.put("dummyurl", JSON.stringify(data)).then(
            function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            },
            function(response) {
                deferred.reject(response);
            })
        return deferred.promise;
 };

 return model;
}]);
```

Same goes for rest of the tabs.
There is one run button on header which broadcasts the "SaveAll".

**Now the question is :**

I want to run some process on server when "SaveAll" is finished on each tab. There are around 5-6 tabs. How do I know that "SaveAll" is finished on all the tabs? ( individual tab controller js files are loaded at runtime using lazy load)

Comment: would be a lot simpler if you only had one tab service wherein you could keep track of how many tabs are currently active and all the requests would pass through that one service. Then you could use array of promises and `$q.all()` to resolve when all the promises are resolved

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use synchronization pattern while calling the save service. Either you can create single save service which uses $q pattern and done the job or else you can use http response pattern(service after service) to achieve synchronization.